# How to make Formula give multiple results across other cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I'm working on an excel sheet, and this is something i really can't figure out.

I want it to be that if the contents of a cell match certain criteria, an entire column of cells will be pasted according to that cell. The cell is a drop down with 32 different options (that can be reduced if theres no way to do it) and each option corresponds to a different column of data. The columns that have to be pasted have roughly 32 cells of data each.

My current formula is basically `=IFS(A1="Potato",Sheet2!G:G)` but this gives me a '0'. The best i can do is change the formula to `=IFS(A1="Potato",Sheet2!G1)` or `=IFS(A1="Potato",Sheet2!G1:G32)` but both of these formulas give me the contents of the first cell only (G1).

Any ideas on how I could get this done without having to contact aliens or build a spaceship?

Answer (score 1):

You can use formulas, or VBA.

I have assumed your 32 columns of source data are in Sheet2 with the headers in row 1.

**Formula Solution**

In Sheet1 A73, enter:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$AF$41,ROW(A1),MATCH($A$1,Sheet2!$A$1:$AF$1,0))
```

Copy this formula to Sheet1 A74:A105

**VBA Solution**

Put this code in the Sheet1 module;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With Sheet2
            Set c = .Rows(1).Find(what:=Sheet1.Range("A1").Value)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                Set c = Intersect(.UsedRange, c.EntireColumn)
                Sheet1.Range("A73").Resize(c.Rows.Count, 1).Delete
                c.Copy Sheet1.Range("A73")
            End If
        End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED ANSWER:**  *(according to comment)*

We have the following layout of products

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'first we check the user input
Dim u_input As String
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
u_input = LCase(Trim(ws.Range("A1").Value2))

'now we need to determine how many columns there are so we know when to stop looping
Dim lc As Long, lr As Long
lc = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

' loops through all the products
For Each cell In Range(Cells(1, "F"), Cells(1, lc))
    ' if the product matches the input
    If LCase(Trim(cell)) = u_input Then
        lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, cell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        ' copy and paste the active data range to A37
        ws.Range(Cells(1, cell.Column), Cells(lr, cell.Column)).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A37").PasteSpecial
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

So, upon entering cucumber and clicking the button:

[image]

We would get the following result:

[image]

You can add any number of products there, as long as the first product starts in column F. (though that can also be changed in code).

---

**PS:** This will however end up overwriting your data and also cause data to overlap if your data ranges are not the same. It probably would be smarter to paste the data into the next empty row in sheet2 instead of directly to A37

This can be achieved by changing the line
`Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A37").PasteSpecial` to `Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells((Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, "A")).PasteSpecial`

Comment: Sorry I missed that! The area i want to paste it to is in Cell A73. So I wanted to paste those 32 cells as from there. As for the column, there are 32 different columns that i need. So if A1=potato, then all the information about potato will be pasted as from A73. If A1=Cucumber, different column, etc.

Comment: @Attractivetoaster check the edited answer, ps: i messed up and made the range 37 instead of 73. Though that can easily be edited in code.